# How to get a parametrically representation from a line

Tags: calculus

I have this question:

The equations 
$$
x-1 = \frac{1}{2}(y-2) = \frac{1}{3}(z-2)
$$

describe a line. The same path is given parametrically by $x=1+t$, what are the parametric representations of $y$ and $z$?

I am a bit lost, can anybody help me?

David

Answer (score 1):

Just set each "side" of your equation equal to $t$.  For $x$, we obtain $x-1=t$ which gives the answer you mention.  For $y$, we have:

$$\frac{1}{2}(y-2)=t\quad \Longrightarrow\quad y=2t+2$$

I'll let you try to find the parametric equation for $z$.

Comment: 20 seconds apart - close as always. +1 :)